# Cannot boot: BusyBox (initramfs)

Tags: initramfs, busybox

My ubuntu 14.04 lts 64bit not booting up, it shows :

```
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is what several users discussed here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247265

The discussion there is long, and people seem to have used various methods to resolve the issue for their systems. However, here's a portion of a post that seemed to be the most help to many people (since there doesn't seem to be one specific solution, you'll probably have to experiment with the various solutions proposed):

> Hey, everyone. The solution that I posted has something of a major flaw: it's not that it's wrong, it just isn't a permanent fix. In order to make the changes permanent, you actually have to edit your GRUB file. Another Linux-user who found the solution I posted emailed me about it, and this is what I sent him in reply:
>
> Hi,
>
> I found at this link a thread in wich people discussed about exactly my problem. And you were the only one that posted an answer and I don' t understand something in that answer and that's how you found the boot commands.
>   Please give me un answer my Ubuntu 14.04 is installed but I can' t acces it :(
>
> Thanks
>   Adrian Ciucanel
>
> 10:22 AM (6 hours ago)
>
> to me
>   I forgot the link: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/247265
>   Daniel Williams
>
> 2:20 PM (2 hours ago)
>
> to Adrian
>
> A couple of questions first:
>
> - When you start up, does your computer give you a couple of OS options, i.e. Windows, Ubuntu?
> - Assuming the answer is yes, choosing Ubuntu, are you taken to a burgundy screen titled GNU GRUB version 2.02 (or some variation thereof) ?
>
> If yes, use the up/down arrow keys to prevent the GRUB screen from automatically choosing Ubuntu. Then, highlight the Ubuntu option. There should be an option at the bottom of the grub screen to edit commands before booting (mine has 'e' as the hot-button).
>
> Once you hit the command edit hot-button, you should see a block of boot commands. Keep in mind that you will have separate boot commands for every boot option.
>
> Caution: all of the information I'm sending you is stuff I've figured out through tinkering with my computer, and I am by NO means a Linux expert. I can't guarantee that this will solve your problem, and honestly, it's a solution I found on another site.
>   Daniel Williams
>
> 4:57 PM (3 minutes ago)
>
> to Adrian
>   Hey, Adrian, I recently discovered that the solution I gave on the site is not a permanent fix. It works, but in order to make the changes permanent, you'll have to go into your grub.cfg file in your boot/grub folder and make the same changes in the file. It's read-only if you just try to open it, so you'll have to use this command in your terminal to access the file without restrictions: sudo gedit ... Once you open gedit, you'll have to browse for grub.cfg. Unfortunately I don't know how to open files directly from the terminal (although I'm certain there's a way to do it).